# Store data in multiple table of different component from single component in joomla

Tags: php, database, components, joomla2.5

Is it possible to store data in multiple table of different component from single component ?

I want to store data of `com_ccnewsletter` on both `com_ccnewsletter` and `com_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can untill an unless you know the table structure & what data you want to store into it. Its just matter of writing a query into your component.

Comment: Thank you atpatil11 for your response, i did it.